# To run sqlldr in a shell script

Tags: sql, shell, unix

Hi I'm writing a small shell script that will load data from a .ctl file in DB but should not display the output on the screen after executing the script, as it's critical, just wanted to confirm whether this is correct or not:

```
#!/bin/ksh

Y=`sqlldr usr/passwd@DB control = /work/ctlm/SCRIPTS/upload.ctl`
echo $Y > sqlldr_1
rm -rf sqlldr_1
```

Comment: Is there any reason to pass output to a variable, why not redirect directly. And why write to a file and then remove it?

Comment: I don't want the output of the sqlldr to be displayed on the screen after executing the script, what should I do?

Comment: on the screen you have 2 output streams : stdout and stderr, if you don't want output, use redirection ; examples in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shell the spaces are used to separate arguments, remove them around `=`.
Also use quotes around variable $Y to keep format (spaces, newlines).

```
#!/bin/ksh

Y=`sqlldr usr/passwd@DB control=/work/ctlm/SCRIPTS/upload.ctl`
echo "$Y" > sqlldr_1
rm -rf sqlldr_1
```

If you don't want any output to screen, then use redirection

For example, to remove output

```
sqlldr usr/passwd@DB control=/work/ctlm/SCRIPTS/upload.ctl >/dev/null 2>&1
```

To create 2 files out.log and err.log

```
sqlldr usr/passwd@DB control=/work/ctlm/SCRIPTS/upload.ctl >out.log 2>err.log
```

fd 1 is implicit, `>out.log` is the same as `1>out.log`
spaces can be added between `>` and filename,
but there must not be space between file descriptor and `>`

Comment: Can we directly use control=upload.ctl like below: `sqlldr usr/passwd@DB control=upload.ctl`   or do we necessarily have to give the whole path  like I mentioned in my original post?

Comment: yes maybe depending your current working directory, you can try. Also don't forget to vote and mark as answered.